# Undefined property $id for users. But user has ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I'm attempting to build up a query in Laravel.

I have two tables, with the following attirbuteds

**User**

- id (auto)
- name
- email
- userType
- password

**TenantPreferance**

- id (auto)
- county
- type
- user_id (this is the user who created their
  preference)

I'm trying to get a collection of data from users of a certain type where id of the user, matches the user_id in preferences.

But I get this error

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$id

```
$tenants = User::where('userType', 'tenant');
    $Prefereances = TenantPreferance::where($tenants->id, $Prefereances->user_id);
    $users = $Prefereances->get();
```

Comment: $tenants = `User::where('userType', 'tenant')->first();`

Comment: what is the relation between tenant and preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for : $tenants = User::where('userType', 'tenant');
must add:
first()

```
$tenants = User::where('userType', 'tenant')->first();
```

or : get()

```
 $tenants = User::where('userType', 'tenant')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have the preferances stored in a variable called $user, but it doesn't have the user name (obviously), is it possible to get that based of $tenants?

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually run the built sql. You also need to get a singular event of it out. So im using first() in this instance. Like this

    `$tenants = User::where('userType', 'tenant')->first();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$tentants =  User::with('TenantPreferance')->where('userType', 'tenant')->get();
```

where TenantPreferance is the relationship name